# How do I access resources file from a referenced library project?

Tags: asp.net, embedded-resource, class-library

I have an ASP.Net website, "MyApp", which contains the following resources files:

1. WebResources.resx
2. WebResources.es.resx

The website references a library project, "MyLib" from which I want to access those resources files.  Here is the code I'm attempting:

```
var rm = new ResourceManager("MyApp", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
subject = rm.GetString("HelloMessage"); //always string.empty
```

The problem is that the executing assembly is always "MyLib" instead of "MyApp".  Is it possible to access the resource files embedded in the website project from a library project?

Thanks for any help,
-Keith

Answer (score 0):

var res= HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(resourceFile, resourceKey);

replace resourceFile with the resource file name (Without .resx).

replace resourceKey with the key name .

```
public static string GetResourceString(string resourceFile, string resourceKey)
{
 if (HttpContext.Current == null)
     return resourceKey;
 var res = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(resourceFile, resourceKey);
 if (res == null)
 {
     // Log missing key here
     // ....
     res = resourceKey;
 }
 return res;
}
```